# Evaluating the integral $\int e^{tx - 2|x|} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I need to evaluate the following integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{tx - 2|x|} dx \tag*{for $t \in (-2, 2)$}$$

To attempt to evaluate this, I being by splitting the integral in two:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{tx - 2|x|} dx \\
= \int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{tx + 2x} dx + \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{tx - 2x} dx \\
\text{Let }u = tx + 2x\text{,  }du = t + 2 dx\\ 
\text{Let }v = tx - 2x\text{,  }dv = t - 2 dx\\ 
= \int_{-\infty}^{0} \frac{e^{u}}{t + 2} du + \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{v}}{t - 2} dv \\
= \frac{1}{t + 2}\int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{u} du + \frac{1}{t - 2}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{v}dv \\
= \frac{1}{t + 2}(1) + \frac{1}{t - 2}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{tx - 2x} dx \\
$$
At this point I was unsure how to proceed, so I went to Wolfram Alpha to see how it evaluted the integral. Wolfram Alpha gives the following for the indefinite integral:
$$
\int e^{tx - 2|x|} dx
= \begin{cases} 
\frac{e^{tx + 2x}}{t + 2} & x < 0 \\ 
\frac{(t+2)e^{tx - 2x}-4}{t^2 - 4} & x > 0 \\
0 & x = 0
\end{cases}
$$

How do I proceed with evaluating this integral so no integral terms remain, and how does what I've found for the improper integral (if correct) reconcile with Wolfram Alpha's indefinite integral results?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\left.\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{tx - 2\verts{x}}\,\dd x
\,\right\vert_{\ t\ \in\ \pars{-2,2}} & =
\int_{0}^{\infty}
\bracks{\expo{tx - 2\verts{x}} + \expo{t\pars{-x} - 2\verts{-x}}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] &=
\int_{0}^{\infty}
\bracks{\expo{-\pars{2 - t}x} + \expo{-\pars{2 + t}x}}\,\dd x =
\left.{\expo{-\pars{2 - t}x} \over t - 2} +
{\expo{-\pars{2 + t}x} \over -t - 2}\right\vert_{\ 0}^{\ \infty}
\\[5mm] & =
-\,{1 \over t - 2} - {1 \over -t - 2} =
\bbx{\ds{4 \over 4 - t^{2}}}
\end{align}

> Note that
>   $\ds{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mrm{f}\pars{x}\,\dd x =
> \int_{0}^{\infty}\bracks{\mrm{f}\pars{x}+ \mrm{f}\pars{-x}}\,\dd x}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$\int\limits_{-\infty}^0e^{tx+2x}dx=\int\limits_{-\infty}^0e^{(t+2)x}=(\dfrac{e^{(t+2)x}}{t+2})\big|_{-\infty}^0=\dfrac{e^{(t+2)\cdot 0}}{t+2}-\lim\limits_{y\to -\infty}\dfrac{e^{(t+2)y}}{t+2}=\dfrac{e^0}{t+2}-0=\dfrac{1}{t+2}$

No need to use substitution because we integrate with respect to $x$. Other integral is evaluated similarly.